# What prevents chaos theory from being the principle of a deterministic universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory, determinism

One could potentially suggest observations of atomic locations partly with chaos theory by suggesting that the seemingly random pattern simply results from a sufficiently small Lyapunov time that allows nearby trajectories to diverge very quickly, making randomness and chaotic trajectories indistinguishable.

However, the inverse of Lyapunov time should not be faster enough such that trajectories diverge faster than the speed of light, but this is very difficult to assess with individual particles that are either entangled or which cannot have simultaneous position and momentum determined.

In the observational constraints and in seeing the simpler explanation of deterministic chaos, why can't quantum randomness potentially be explained by chaotic motion? It seems physicists already possess the capability to predict the exact future state of single particles at a time at least.

Comment: How would you use chaos to explain, e.g., the interference pattern observed in the one-electron-at-a-time double-slit experiment?

Comment: Can waves not exhibit chaotic motion?

Comment: Yes, they can -- but my take from your post was that you wanted to replace the description by wave functions and (e.g.) collapse by a description based on chaotic particles, maybe hidden-variables-like. If not, your question might be to vague/broad to be on topic. So, please, what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: I don't "want" to replace anything, that is your own confrontational prejudice in an elitist physics community that you are projecting onto me. I am simply asking on why it is/isn't possible given that seemingly random observations seem to be capable of explanation through chaotic behavior. Bell's inequality experiments, as far as I know, also do not rule out hidden non-local variables.

Comment: Hey, PhiEarl, I am by no means looking for confront, nor, I hope, being prejudiced - my "want to" should perhaps have been "suggest to". So, please, answer my question, because your post is still not clear to me. Is chaotic classical particles instead of mainstream QM what you have in mind? How could that describe interference?

Comment: You're question intrinsically doesn't make sense to me. I am myself trying to assess why this assertion is/isn't possible. It seems as though there exists some capacity for randomness in QM to be explained by chaotic behavior, but obviously I am not the first person who thought of that, so as many scientists continue to assume quantum randomness exists, what is it about chaos theory that is insufficient to explain the randomness exhibited in particles?

Comment: I guess what I was trying to get to, is that QM has more to it then randomness alone and that I can't see how chaos could explain things like entanglement or interference. But now it seems to me that you don't dispute this, that the only aspect you thought chaos might be an alternative explanation is randomness. Is that correct?

Comment: @stafusa I don't see how randomness explains entanglement or interference. I can see how deterministic wave mechanics do however. In fact, determinism provides the exact frame work for the evolution of wave functions. It is only the observations upon wave function collapse, a phenomenon that is poorly understood, which appears random.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant with "I can't see how chaos could explain things like entanglement or interference. But now it seems to me that **you don't dispute this**" - i.e., they're distinct aspects of QM. As for your question, all I can offer is that my impression is that it shouldn't be impossible to do, but no one felt compelled so far to try to come up with such a model for whatever reason - perhaps because once you assume hidden variables you don't need chaotic dynamics to explain the 'apparent' randomness.

Comment: Well assuming hidden local variables would contradict the experimental evidence of Bell's inequality. Hidden global variables however, similar to what Richard Feynman conjectured in electrons being identical, could. In either case, one could postulate observations across the universe as a series of observations conforming to chaotic motion, but then I would not see a current mechanism by which this is actualized, which is the nature of the uncertainty in how to describe wave function collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Let's postulate that every possible physical observable follows a chaotic (but deterministic) evolution rule such that, over any "reasonable" amount of time, their "long-term" behavior is effectively random with statistics that precisely match the predictions made by quantum mechanics.

A notable challenge to such a description of physical behavior is relativity, notably the universal speed limit. To see this, consider a particle in free space whose chaotic behavior is consistent with a probability density that is uniform over a small, finite region of space. As time goes on, the probability density is predicted to keep spreading out by quantum mechanics—inevitably to the point where the underlying chaotic dynamics of the particle would have to make the particle travel faster than light in order for its statistics to be consistent with the quantum mechanical prediction (i.e. for the particle to "visit" all regions of its nonzero probability density function). You might say that the underlying chaotic behavior of the particle is exempt from relativity to adjust for this, but you can imagine the can of worms that such an assumption would open.

Ultimately, even if some convoluted version of this was viable, it would still only be a worthy contender for a novel physical theory if it generated novel testable behavior, which would be impossible at any time scale that we can currently test at. (This is by construction—we postulate that the chaotic evolution rule matches all current quantum mechanical predictions by definition.)

Comment: I don't quite see how this follows. Trajectories of particles in chaotic motion would be just as affected by length contraction and time dilation as any other trajectory, the Lyapunov time itself would be adjusted based on the relativity of observations. There's nothing special about chaotic motion, it is only that in a closed system it possess an inherent unpredictability.